# XMLHttpRequest MVC data post

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, xmlhttprequest

*Here i am trying to post the data to my MVC Controller here below is the code in javascript.*

```
var xmlhttp; 
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();}
        else { xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"); }

        form = new FormData();
        form.append('txtMobile1', txtMobile1);
        form.append('_resId', _resId);

        xmlhttp.open("POST", "via/checkNumExist");

        xmlhttp.send(form); alert(txtMobile1); alert(_resId); alert(xmlhttp.responseText);
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
            //alert(checkMobNumExist);
            if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {

                alert(xmlhttp.responseText);

                checkMobNumExist = xmlhttp.responseText;}
```

*Here is the code i have made in MVC controller below*

```
public JsonResult checkNumExist()
    {
        string result = "0";
        string mob = Request.Form["txtMobile1"],Resid = Request.Form["_resId"];
        query = "SPcheckNumExist";
        if(CommonFunctions.MobileIsValid(mob) && mob.Length == 10)
        {
            param = new SqlParameter[] 
            {
                new SqlParameter("@mobile", SqlDbType.VarChar,12),
                new SqlParameter("@ResID", SqlDbType.VarChar,100)
            };
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(mob)) param[0].Value = mob; else param[0].Value = DBNull.Value;
            if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Resid)) param[1].Value = Resid; else param[1].Value = DBNull.Value;

            var obj = SqlHelper.ExecuteScalar(con, CommandType.StoredProcedure, query, param);
            if (obj != null) result = obj.ToString();
        }
        //return result;
        return Json(result);
    }
```

*I have tried this MVC method with string rather than JSON still debugger doesn't start at this controller and also xmlhttp.onreadystatechange doesn't reach result.*

Comment: you need to add `[HttpPost]` attribute on top of your action for a post catll to hit your action.

Comment: what's the name of your controller ?